# Alternative definition for the symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was trying to solve a problem from a set theory book and the set $\{x| x \in A \leftrightarrow x \notin B \}$ popped up. After thinking about it for some time, I realized that this set represents the      symmetric difference of the sets A and B. Is this correct? If so why not use this short and compact definition when defining symmetric difference?

Comment: Because that's a hard expression to parse. It consists of all $x$ for which the biconditional holds; so it consists of all $x$ for which either $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ are both true, or both are false; so it consists of all $x$ for which either $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, or $x\notin A$ and $x\in B$. "Compactness" is not the be all and end all of definitions: understandability, digestability, parsability are  also important considerations.  (In addition, in standard set theory you would then need to prove that this is a set, since we don't have unrestricted comprehension)

Comment: In other words, as much as possible, you want definitions to be something people will understand immediately, not "after thinking about it for some time".